# Get signature from pem file

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I use this command to generate pem certificate: `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`

How I can get signature value for this pem file?

Comment: PEM files as such aren't signed, but an X.509 certificate _is_ and one of your PEM files contains such a certificate. The programming answer using openssl is PEM_read[_bio]_X509 plus [X509_get0_signature](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/X509_get0_signature.html); a nonprogramming answer would be offtopic.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I hope you're not trying to imply command-line solutions are not on-topic.  [Shell programming is programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sh).  Thus command-line solutions using `openssl x509 ...` are certainly on-topic.

Comment: Peter, do you mean certificate fingerprint possibly? Generally we can not do anything with the signature other than to verify the "to-be-signed" part of the certificate using the public key of the parent certificate; *those* functions are generally available. If you just want to inspect the size / value then you can use `openssl x509 -text`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is about getting the fingerprints/digests of the certificate:

SHA-256:

`openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha256 -inform pem -in [certificate-file.crt]`

SHA-1:

`openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha1 -inform pem -in [certificate-file.crt]`

MD5:

`openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -md5 -inform pem -in [certificate-file.crt]`